# cakephp3 load library inside a method

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Just migrated a system to the new cake3.
However now due to namespaces, struggling to dynamically load libraries inside methods.

I have a controller

with this in :

```
require_once(APP . 'Lib' . DS  . 'Channel' . DS  . 'Channel1.php');
require_once(APP . 'Lib' . DS  . 'Channel' . DS  . 'Channel2.php');
require_once(APP . 'Lib' . DS  . 'Channel' . DS  . 'Channel3.php');
require_once(APP . 'Lib' . DS  . 'Channel' . DS  . 'Channel4.php');
use Channel\Channel1;
use Channel\Channel2;
use Channel\Channel3;
```

However I don't want to load all the libraries unless I need them.  Any suggestions for a good solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put the files in `src/Channel` instead of`src/Lib/Channel` then the autoloader will find automatically your files when you do

`use App\Channel\Channel1;`

It will require that you set the namespace of the class to `App\Channel`

You can also tell composer how to autoload your custom namespace. In your `composer .json`'s autoload section, under `psr-4`, do:

```
"Channel\\" : "./src/Lib/Channel"
```

And finally execute `composer dumpautoload`